# Android Studio can't find com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:5.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I'm trying to build my Android Project but when I rebuild I receive this error message:

> Could not find com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:5.1.2.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.pom
>
> file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.jar
>       file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.pom
>       file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.jar
>       file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.pom
>       file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.jar
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.pom
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/5.1.2/butterknife-compiler-5.1.2.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :app

This is my build.gradle module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wakeup.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:5.1.2'


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton/butterknife
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    google() // <--here
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google() // <-- here
}
 }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your project `:app` is missing a butter knife reference. This normally happens when you forgot to define your module dependencies correctly. Please post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: just added tanks

Answer (score 0):

Your project `:app` is missing a butter knife reference. From the [documentation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) this is what you are missing:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Also, the version you are using `5.1.2` does not exists:

> {   "errors" : [ {
>       "status" : 404,
>       "message" : "Could not find resource"   } ] }

Try the following file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wakeup.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Comment: The version you are using does not exist. Check my edited answer.

Comment: But when I do this I receive this error:    > Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
  - butterknife-5.1.2.jar (butterknife-5.1.2.jar)
Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.